# ssh from Fedora 33 to Debian NAS - always asks for password

Tags: debian, ssh, fedora

I have a WD MyBook Duo (old, but it works well) acting as a NAS device, and I have an rsync backup script set up similar to [this](https://netcodger.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/rsync-backup-to-my-book-live/).

At this point, I can run the backup system but every time it asks for a password - this didn't happen until recently upgraded to Fedora 33 - not sure why.

I've gone through all the standard processes:

- Run ssh-keygen on client, and copy id_rsa.pub content to authorized_keys on server
- Verify permissions - .ssh directory on server is 700; authorized_keys on server is 600; .ssh directory on client is 700; id_rsa on client is 600; id_rsa.pub on client is 644; known_hosts on client in 644

Anytime I log in (as root or any other user), I'm always asked for a password.  To try to diagnose what is happening, I ran `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` on the server, and then tried to log in from the client with `ssh -p 2222 <user@server>`, but the output didn't really help - it is below.

Also went through steps of using `ssh-add` on both the client or the server, but neither changed the results.

Finally, I tried adjusting my ssh-config file (also below).  I see that the `RSAAuthentication` yes line is commented out, so I uncommented it and restarted the service with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` - no luck.

And, there I'm stuck.  Any suggestions what you do next?

EDIT:
Based on comments from @patbarron, I tried using ecdsa instead of RSA - same results.  Also verified that `authorized_keys` is owned by root - I'm trying to login as root for now for a different reason and will shift to another user later.  Same results.

I also added output from running `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2222` on the host and `ssh -p 2222` on the guest.  Within the output, I see the message `mm_auth_password: user not authenticated` but I don't see anything that tells me why that's happening.

---

ssh debug output

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.144 port 57186
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 101/65534
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.144"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Failed none for root from 192.168.1.144 port 57186 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for root
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.144 port 57186 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: root has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/2
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 42 (0x2a)
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

---

ssh_config

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

---

output when running /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2222 on the host, then executing ssh -p 2222 from the guest

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 656
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 656
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:5 setting Port 22
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:9 setting Protocol 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:11 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:12 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:14 setting UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:17 setting KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:18 setting ServerKeyBits 768
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:21 setting SyslogFacility LOCAL3
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:22 setting LogLevel INFO
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:25 setting LoginGraceTime 120
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:26 setting PermitRootLogin yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:27 setting StrictModes yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:28 setting AllowUsers root
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:30 setting RSAAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:31 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:35 setting IgnoreRhosts yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:37 setting RhostsRSAAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:39 setting HostbasedAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:44 setting PermitEmptyPasswords no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:48 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:63 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:64 setting X11DisplayOffset 10
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:65 setting PrintMotd no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:66 setting PrintLastLog yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:67 setting TCPKeepAlive yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:74 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:76 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:78 setting UsePAM yes
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 656
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.144 port 60860
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 12958
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: privsep user:group 101:65534
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 101/65534
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 0
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 0
debug3: mm_answer_moduli: got parameters: 2048 8192 8192
debug3: mm_choose_dh: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_MODULI
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 1
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 1
debug3: mm_choose_dh: remaining 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug2: monitor_read: 0 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 268/512
debug2: bits set: 4095/8192
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug2: bits set: 4103/8192
debug3: mm_key_sign entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 5
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 5
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 6
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x2073df70(271)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: monitor_read: 5 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 8
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 7
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.1.144.
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 656
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for root
debug3: mm_start_pam entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 48
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 3
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
debug3: mm_auth_password entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 11
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 12
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug2: monitor_read: 7 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 48
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.144"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 48 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 3
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 3 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 11
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12
debug3: mm_auth_password: user not authenticated
Failed none for root from 192.168.1.144 port 60860 ssh2
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password
debug3: mm_auth_password entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 11
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 12
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 11
debug3: PAM: sshpam_passwd_conv called with 1 messages
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for root
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12
debug3: mm_auth_password: user authenticated
debug3: mm_do_pam_account entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 49
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 50
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 49
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_pam_account: called
debug3: PAM: do_pam_account pam_acct_mgmt = 0 (Success)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 50
debug3: mm_do_pam_account returning 1
debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending new keys: 0x2073db38 0x2073da30
debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x2073db38
debug3: mm_newkeys_to_blob: converting 0x2073da30
debug3: mm_send_keystate: New keys have been sent
debug3: mm_send_keystate: Sending compression state
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 25
debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state
Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.144 port 60860 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: root has been authenticated by privileged process
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 25
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x20743238(139)
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for second key
debug3: mm_newkeys_from_blob: 0x20743238(139)
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting compression state
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Getting Network I/O buffers
debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync
debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync end
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug3: PAM: opening session
debug3: PAM: sshpam_store_conv called with 1 messages
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/1
debug3: tty_parse_modes: SSH2 n_bytes 261
debug3: tty_parse_modes: ospeed 38400
debug3: tty_parse_modes: ispeed 38400
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 42 (0x2a)
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug2: Setting env 0: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug2: Ignoring env request LANGUAGE: disallowed name
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug2: Ignoring env request XMODIFIERS: disallowed name
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 0: rfd 9 isatty
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

Comment: In version 33 Fedora increased their cryptographic settings as seen at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2. You can try to enable compatibility mode with `update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:FEDORA32`. See if that helps in using the key instead of a password.

Comment: The SSH server on the Debian machine is really really old (version 5.1), no wonder you can't connect to it using the more stricter version of SSH on Fedora 33.

Comment: Yes,  I mentioned in my original post that the NAS OS is quite old.  I think it is 2012, actually.  As it is, I'm not sure I can upgrade (not simply) since it is a specialized system.  That being said, I haven't tried.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do to create compatibility between the two systems?  I obviously don't want to compromise my entire Fedora system, but surely I can make an adjustment for this one ip addess or for a specific user.

Comment: I obviously don't want to compromise my entire Fedora system, but surely I can make an adjustment for this one ip addess or for a specific user.  I also looked into updated the OpenSSH package, but the system is so old, no package is available.  Attempting to build from source is a problem as there is no C compiler on the system.  Short of a full OS upgrade, I don't think I can update it.

Comment: I also tried simply exporting the target folder and mounting it on the guest system.  This works, but rsync is incredibly slow in this configuration for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 33 changed the default crypto policy such that `ssh-rsa` keys are no longer accepted for login.  You'll need to generate a new key with a more secure type (such as by `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa`).  Then, paste the relevant public key produced by this into your `authorized_keys` file.

The new default crypto policy for `opensshserver` will accept these key types:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.
com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.c
om,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp
521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@op
enssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha
2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@opens
sh.com
```

(You could also change the default crypto policy on your system to accept these keys, but I wouldn't recommend it.)

Comment: That seems like a good option, but I'm still having the same problem with an ecdsa key.

Comment: Argh...  One other thing that you might check, if you have not done so already, is to confirm that the `authorized_keys` file is owned by the user you're trying to log in as - sometimes that trips me up.

Comment: Yep.  Got that.  Another wrinkle - maybe helpful, maybe not - I can ssh between two different Fedora 33 machines using rsa by the normal steps that I detailed above - ssh-keygen, copy id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys.  I can ssh both directions doing this with the two F33 machines, but the Duo gives the same results from each of the F33s.  Puzzling.

Comment: Try: /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2222 and collect new debug data.  The -ddd should give more detail vs. a single -d

Comment: Thanks for the note and I apologize for the slow reply.  I ran sshd with -ddd as you suggested, and have included the output in my original post.